# Oracle Connection closed

Tags: oracle, connection, pool

I have a Java web application, that uses Apache DBCP to connect to an Oracle DB. The connection is done using JNDI. In my application, I need to run a a query to the database, process the results and then save the updates. 
The problem is that no matter what properties I set for the db connection parameters (maxWait, minEvictableIdleTimeMillis, testOnBorrow, etc - I have tried all of them with different values), I always receive back a "connection closed" error, after aprox. 2.5 min. The result set I process is large, and the execution takes longer than 2.5 mins, but even if I do the paginated query, to hit the database often, I still get the same error. 
Another strange thing is that, no matter what value I set for the connection pool size (with maxActive, maxIdle, initialSize), if I log the max physical open connections the value is 1. 
Do you have any idea why this happens? Could this be caused by a setting on DB / network side?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to multiple issues.

1) All the changes that you have made are on client side. You should probably look in other areas too.
2) Check oracle/server side setting's such as sqlnet.ora and maximum number of connections/session and processes allowed at the database level.
3) Check if there are any soft/hard firewall settings that are closing your session/connection. This may be the reason for your "connection closed".

Thanks
Rahul